# How to Observable map collection of json objects with different property names

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an json result which is a collection of objects. I need to cast them to a collection of custom objects which have different property names than the json result. Also not all result properties are needed in this instance.

**JSON**

```
[{"empID":"12345", "formattedName":"Simpson, Homer"},
 {"empID":"24680", "formattedName":"Simpson, Marge"},
 {"empID":"36912", "formattedName":"Simpson, Bart"},
 {"empID":"13579", "formattedName":"Simpson, Lisa"},
 {"empID":"13579", "formattedName":"Simpson, Lisa"}]
```

**My Custom Ojbect**

```
export class multiSelect {
   constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string
  ) {  }
}
```

**Service**

```
  reportsTo(): Observable<multiSelect> {
    return this._http.get('getCollection')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .map(({empID, formattedName}) => new multiSelect(empID, formattedName))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I would like for my service to return this

```
[{"id":"12345", "name":"Simpson, Homer"},
 {"id":"24680", "name":"Simpson, Marge"},
 {"id":"36912", "name":"Simpson, Bart"},
 {"id":"13579", "name":"Simpson, Lisa"},
 {"id":"13579", "name":"Simpson, Lisa"}]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of how your current code isn't doing what you want it to do? Is the compiler giving you an error? Is it throwing an exception when run? Is it giving different output than what you want it to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map your data to your class like so:

```
reportsTo() {
  return this._http.get('getCollection')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json().map(res => new multiSelect(res.empID, res.formattedName)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

That should do what you want. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a method in the `multiSelect` class:

```
export class multiSelect {
   constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string
  ) {  }
  fillWithData(data){ //this function receive your json
       this.id = data.empID;
       this.name = data.formattedName;
  }
}
```

Then, a `JSON.strigify(multiSelectInstance)` would do the trick.

If you want to keep using the constructor so you only need one call you can make the following:

```
export class multiSelect {
   constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public data
  ) { 
       this.id = data.empID;
       this.name = data.formattedName;
   }
  fillWithData(data){ //this function receive your json
       this.id = data.empID;
       this.name = data.formattedName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to change your service to something like this:

```
reportsTo(): Observable<multiSelect> {
  return this._http.get('getCollection')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .map(({empID, formattedName}) => ({id: empID, name: formattedName}))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then get rid of your `multiSelect` class and instead replace it with an interface.

```
export interface multiSelect {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Typescript will enforce the returned observable has the data in the correct format because of the interface, and now you don't have to deal with classes or constructors.

Comment: Would like to go with this method but I get red squiggly lines (TS errors) under id and empID.  Errors like "[ts] unused labe1" and "[ts] Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects" respectively.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the syntax was a bit off and I didn't test after I wrote it. The edited answer should work.